# How can I deploy with apache my django app using a virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I deployed my django app on my apache server. Now, I would like to use a virtualenv on my apache server. How can I do that ?

I thought to that :

```
virtualenv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
```

But it works only for my terminal not my django app...

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Show us your relevant Apache configuration!

Comment: Apache on Windows or Linux?